# static webpage change file

Tags: javascript, html, http, github-pages

I'm making a simple website in GitHub pages. I have a text file in the /docs folder (I can move though) and I want to change it's content through index.html. I found a lot of back-end solutions but GitHub pages allows static webpages only. Is there a way to do so in static webpage and if so how to do it in javascript?

Comment: Consider using AJAX/front-end frameworks to do such a thing, where based on a static file (recommended format: `json`) you can manipulate the page accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Since it's static pages, you can't rewrite the hosted file from the front end client. To update the text file contents, you'll need to do it through the github interface, or as a commit into your repository unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

No.

Changing content on the server requires code that runs on the server.

If you could do it with client side code, then every website would rapidly become defaced.

The closest you could do would be to store data on the client (e.g. via localstorage) and then have a script on the page read that data and edit the DOM locally. Obviously, changing the data would change it only for the particular browser and not for all visitors.

Answer (score 0):

There are two answers to your question:

1. Technically, it is possible to change files on GitHub from a script:

   GitHub's API allows you to update files through an HTTP request.

   You could use Javascript to modify the contents of a file, and then send a request to GitHub's API to update that file. There are a few libraries that make it really easy to work with the API, but from here you have to figure it out yourself.

   Here is the documentation for this: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#update-a-file
2. Conceptually, it sounds like you are doing something wrong. Static webpages are called *static* because nothing changes. If you want to have dynamic content, you should really look into other solutions.

Comment: It's really a small project, so I prefer hosting it on GitHub

Comment: Then give it a try. One issue you need to solve is how to allow changes to your repository through the API, since I am not sure if you can change files without authentication. We modify files from our servers using a personal access token, but you don't really want to share that with anybody. You could set up authentication through GitHub and use the user's OAuth token, but then they need to have a GitHub account.